# Extending types to support nested modules

Tags: typescript, apollo-server

I am trying to define a generic Typescript interface that will enforce a pattern on exports from a series of modules. Each module will export pieces of an Apollo GraphQL server that can be stitched together to aid in scalability.

For example let's say that I have a folder called `News` that has the following structure:

```
News
 |_ index.ts
 |_ typeDefs.ts
 |_ resolvers.ts
 |_ dataSources
     |_ index.ts
     |_ SourceA.ts
     |_ SourceB.ts
```

In `index.ts` for News I have defined the following:

```
import { IResolvers } from "apollo-server";
import { DocumentNode } from "graphql";
import * as DataSources from "./datasources";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";
import schema from "./typeDefs";

export interface IContext {
  dataSources: {
    [R in keyof typeof DataSources]: InstanceType<typeof DataSources[R]>
  };
}

interface IModule {
  resolvers: IResolvers;
  schema: DocumentNode;
  dataSources: typeof DataSources;
}

export const News: IModule = {
  resolvers,
  schema,
  dataSources: DataSources
};
```

This is behaving exactly as I want it to and it allows me to ensure that the exported News object contains the right DataSources that I can instantiate when needed as well as ensuring that when those DataSources come back on the request context that they will be instances of the DataSources I have defined.

What I want to do next is be able to apply `IModule` and `IContext` to another module we'll call Foo. Foo has the same structure as News but will export its own DataSources.

How can I modify these types to support more than a single module where DataSources will be nested under each individual module?

**EDIT:**

I was able to update `IModule` by passing in a generic type:

```
interface IModule<TDataSources> {
  resolvers: IResolvers;
  schema: DocumentNode;
  dataSources: TDataSources;
}

const News: IModule<typeof DataSources> = {
  resolvers,
  schema,
  dataSources: DataSources
};
```

And that seems to be working fine.

In general I'm looking to take an object that looks like this:

```
{
  modules: {
    Foo: {
      resolvers,
      schema,
      dataSources: {
        DataSourceA,
        DataSourceB
      },
    },
    Bar: {
      resolvers,
      schema,
      dataSources: {
        DataSourceC,
        DataSourceD
      },
    },
  }
}
```

And turn it into this:

```
{
  DataSourceA,
  DataSourceB,
  DataSourceC,
  DataSourceD
}
```

While maintaining the types on each DataSource. The mapping itself is not a concern its distilling the type of each DataSource from the larger module object to create a union type of all of the DataSources.

Comment: Could you please clarify what would the end interface that combines multiple DataSources should look like? Can be totally invalid TypeScript, but might help to get the idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Grassator - I've provided more details above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you just need a mapped type that would aggregate all data sources into a union type. If that is the case then something like this should work:

```
// this is just for an example, you would have real data instead
declare const data: {
    modules: {
        Foo: IModule<DataSourceA | DataSourceB>,
        Bar: IModule<DataSourceC | DataSourceD>
    }
}

type AllDataSources<T extends { [K in keyof T]: IModule<any> }> =
    T[keyof T]["dataSources"]

type Result = AllDataSources<typeof data["modules"]> // DataSourceA | DataSourceB | DataSourceC | DataSourceD
```

Comment: I think that this is the right approach however AllDataSources would actually contain an instance of each DataSource whereas in the modules they are typeof DataSource. Can you update your answer to reflect that? I've been trying to and struggling. Additionally, can you elaborate on the definition of AllDataSources to help me understand what's happening there? Thanks!